# Is it possible to commit a directory I got doing git clone

Tags: git, github

I have a directory full of things I got from github doing `git clone` (NOT submodules).
I tried to put this directory on git hub but any content of a directory I cloned is not uploaded.
The repo is there `https://github.com/statquant/.vim`
If you look at `vim/bundle` you'll see all the directories I am speaking about, they are all cloned from others. How can I upload what they contain ?

I did the usual

```
git init
git add . or git add -A
git commit -a -m "blah"
...
```

Comment: what directory do you want to upload, and where?

Comment: I want to upload the content of each directory in `.vim/bundle/` to github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But I think you *are* talking about submodules. It sounds like you're trying to clone some other repo into a subdirectory of your own git project. Per the [git-scm book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules), "Git addresses this issue using submodules. Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository." Submodules are how you manage repos embedded in other repos and keep them all up to date.

If all you want is to get the files from another repo into your repo, and you don't care about history or keeping your copy up to date, just copy the project files into your project, leave out the .git directory, and add+commit them as usual. Then it won't be a nested git repo.

Comment: OK! so if I get you right I should remove the `.git` directory in each of these directories I cannot upload and it should work...

Comment: Yes. Updated my answer to try to be more clear. A `.git` dir is a repo, so if you have those nested in your projects, then you *do* have submodules, whether you like it or not. Getting rid of them will change it to the way you're expecting it to work.

Comment: I thought submodules would exhibit a .gitsubmodules somewhere no ?

Comment: I've barely worked with submodules at all, so I can't answer that. From the [git-submodules man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html), it looks like the config file for submodules is `.gitmodules` in the project root. If it's absent, I'd guess you just can't push or pull any submodules, but maybe it falls back to the `.git/config` embedded in each submodule?